# Facebook iPhone SDK, App crashed in pre iOS 4.2, But works fine in iOS 4.2+

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm working on my iPhone app which needs to share an image link on Facebook. It seems everything is ok and working fine on iOS4.2 or more. But in pre iOS4.2 the app is crashing due to exc_bad_access without any error log. I've tried to trace where this bad access is happening but failed to trace.(I tried nszombieenabled)

Any can suggest me any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem. There was no problem in the code. The default Facebook app icon is a *.gif file. Which was causing the crash. I just changed the Icon of the Facebook app from developer.facebook.com and then it worked fine.