# iOS Facebook SDK crashing in iOS 4.1 & 4.2

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, crash

Is it me or anyone else is crashing on those iOS versions with the Facebook SDK.It happens when you're about to share then it gives you a bad access and the debugger says "decodeGIFFrame" ... After a bit research I noticed that the Facebook html is returning an image with null reference "img src="/images/icons/default_app_icon.gif" />" but I don't think that "null" reference of the image causes the crash but the rendering of the gif ... How to repair it?

Edit: BT of the crash

```
#0  0x33ff4938 in decodeGIFFrame ()
#1  0x33ff5ef8 in copyImageBlockSetGIF ()
#2  0x33fe463c in ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback ()
#3  0x31314e4c in CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions ()
#4  0x31314cfc in CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSet ()
#5  0x313149cc in img_blocks_create ()
#6  0x31312248 in img_data_lock ()
#7  0x31310fd0 in CGSImageDataLock ()
#8  0x315b7604 in ripc_AcquireImage ()
#9  0x315b3dfc in ripc_DrawImage ()
#10 0x31310cc4 in CGContextDelegateDrawImage ()
#11 0x31310ae8 in CGContextDrawImage ()
#12 0x34323a48 in WebCore::BitmapImage::checkForSolidColor ()
#13 0x343234d0 in WebCore::BitmapImage::cacheFrame ()
#14 0x343233cc in WebCore::BitmapImage::frameAtIndex ()
#15 0x343226a8 in WebCore::BitmapImage::draw ()
#16 0x34322568 in WebCore::GraphicsContext::drawImage ()
#17 0x343223e8 in WebCore::GraphicsContext::drawImage ()
#18 0x34321f28 in WebCore::RenderImage::paintIntoRect ()
#19 0x3431482c in WebCore::RenderImage::paintReplaced ()
#20 0x34314134 in WebCore::RenderReplaced::paint ()
#21 0x34313e90 in WebCore::RenderImage::paint ()
#22 0x34313e54 in WebCore::InlineBox::paint ()
#23 0x34313e54 in WebCore::InlineBox::paint ()
#24 0x34312c10 in WebCore::InlineFlowBox::paint ()
#25 0x34312790 in WebCore::RootInlineBox::paint ()
#26 0x34223964 in WebCore::RenderLineBoxList::paint ()
#27 0x34220138 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#28 0x34221670 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#29 0x34220a6c in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintFloats ()
#30 0x342201d8 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#31 0x34221670 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#32 0x342207f4 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintChildren ()
#33 0x34220150 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#34 0x34221670 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#35 0x342207f4 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintChildren ()
#36 0x34220150 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#37 0x34221670 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#38 0x342207f4 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintChildren ()
#39 0x34220150 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#40 0x34221670 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#41 0x342207f4 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintChildren ()
#42 0x34220150 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#43 0x34221670 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#44 0x3421e99c in WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayer ()
#45 0x3421ec24 in WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayer ()
#46 0x3421ec24 in WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayer ()
#47 0x3421dce0 in WebCore::RenderLayer::paint ()
#48 0x3421db38 in WebCore::FrameView::paintContents ()
#49 0x30369fb8 in -[WebFrame(WebInternal) _drawRect:contentsOnly:] ()
#50 0x30369dec in -[WebHTMLView drawSingleRect:] ()
#51 0x30369d20 in -[WebHTMLView drawRect:] ()
#52 0x3421d828 in drawCallback ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x4380fffc
```

It happens after the Facebook webView delegate responds on "webViewDidFinishLoad:"

Comment: you may need to show some code (near and including where the crash happens), and also the backtrace as well.

Comment: Edited my post, hope that helps

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue on ios4 :(

Comment: The problem is indeed the GIF image, see this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411307/facebook-iphone-sdk-app-crashed-in-pre-ios-4-2-but-works-fine-in-ios-4-2

Comment: I'm gona try their solution and see if it works, thanks in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to replace in Facebook.m text:

```
static NSString* kDialogBaseURL = @"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/";
```

with

```
static NSString* kDialogBaseURL = @"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/";
```

Comment: Wow it actually worked haha but I would like to know why does it work :P Thanks in advice

Comment: I was having an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when closing the dialog. Changing the kDialogBaseURL value to the one listed above fixed it. Bizarre, but I just wanted to share my experience in case anyone else came across it.